# How to combine these two Postgresql queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert into a first table, then update a second table with the returned (DB generated) UUID of the inserted row before finally returning the result of the insert.

The insert query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.organisations ("name")
VALUES('StackOverflow')
RETURNING *
```

This will return a row with name, data and id. Data is an empty JSON and can be ignored, id is the UUID used below.

The update query looks like this, with `<orgId>` indicating the UUID generated and returned by the above insert and `<userId>` indicating a value passed in from code:

```
UPDATE public.users
SET id_organisation = <orgID>, last_modified_by = <userID>
WHERE id = <userID>;
```

Both of these queries work but I do not know how to string them together and return the output of the first query.

Is it possible to do this or would I be better just running two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CTEs:

```
with i as (
      INSERT INTO public.organisations ("name")
          VALUES('StackOverflow')
          RETURNING *
     )
UPDATE public.users
    SET id_organisation = (SELECT i.id FROM i LIMIT 1),        last_modified_by = <userID>
    WHERE id=<userID>;
```

Note that this uses a subquery with `LIMIT` -- this guarantees that at most one row is returned.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6d05c0508b941611c4d70b02db474825) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to return i at the end of the query? I tried putting RETURNING i as the last line but it just throws an error saying that i is not a column.

Comment: @Exitialis . . . `returning` is valid Postgres syntax and has been for a long, long time.  If you are not really using Postgres, I would advise you to ask *another* question with the correct database tag.

Comment: I know that it is valid syntax, which is why I used it, but it threw an error, hence asking in case I was doing something wrong. Specifically, it says ERROR: column "i" does not exist

Comment: @Exitialis . . . That is why I included a db<>fiddle, where the syntax *does* work.  There is no reference to a column called `i` in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I'd like to return the result of the initial insert query after updating users, hence trying returning i

Comment: @Exitialis . . . Then put the `update` in a CTE and use `select i.* from i` as the outer query.